# How to stop popup login window?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-signin

I am trying to implement google login.At the beginning i was using Client side Google Sign-In but i wanted the login to be in the same browser so I changed to using OAuth2.0 endpoint.I have managed to do this but at the same time the login window still pop ups.I tried removing some codes but it only affected my project in a bad way.Either the button disappears(as i am using a div) or it doesnt redirect anymore.So what should I remove in order to stop the pop up window?

**Codes:**

```
 <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="client_secret.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderButton" async defer></script>
<form method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login</legend>
        <div id="my-signin2" name="login" class="g-signin2" onclick="window.location = '<?php echo $loginURL; ?>'"></div>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: You shouldn't remove it.   The oauth window should always open in a new browser window or popup so that the user can see the url line and know that they are not being sent to a malicious website.

Comment: @DaImTo thats what my boss wants.I followed this tutorial.But i have no idea how to make the button look like Google Login button.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hazMyK_cnzk&t=717s

Comment: I sugest that you not follow two year old YouTube videos.  Things change a lot you should follow the official documentation https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/.   Your boss might want to read up on Oauth2 security while he is at it, sometimes we cant always get what we want.   I once had a boss ask me to remove the password field and only have a login field no one can remember their password.

Comment: @DaImTo Thats what i was using at first.But he feels that popup window is outdated as some websites allow login within the same browser..